# Is apt-cacher-ng ready for multiplatform support?

Tags: debian, apt-get, apt-cache

I have a [Wandboard](http://www.wandboard.org/) running Debian Jessie at home (it's an ARM Cortex-A9). A 3TB HD is attached to it. It's mainly my NAS + Remote Access, but I would like to use it as a caching mirror for apt. (I've 5 other PCs (x86) running Linux at home, and sometimes I need to install the same software on all of them.)

apt-cacher-ng seems to solve this for me, but I was not able to find in the [documentation](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/html/) if it can be used across different architectures.

Is apt-cacher-ng ready for that? If not, is there some tweak that can be be done for that to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, apt-cacher-ng works fine with multiple architectures. I've never noticed any problems from using it with multiple architectures, nor any configuration options related to this. I suspect it's not mentioned in the documentation because it just works. My system has cached .deb files from multiple architectures on it at the moment, and I'm pretty sure I'm using the default configuration.